# EF Core Run Migrations on Multiple Databases Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, database-migration

I'm trying to run migrations on multiple tenants databases, however when I ran the `add-migration initialmigration` and `update-database` command it ran on all tenant databases successfully.

But no I'm adding one more column and running the same procedure. It only applies migration on the last tenant connection string in the list.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MultitenantDbContext>(o => { });
            services.AddTransient<ITenantProvider, TenantProvider>();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "DatabasePerTenant.Core", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

**DbContext class**

```
public class MultitenantDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public long Tenant1Id = 261651;
        public long Tenant2Id = 261658;

        private List<Tenant> Tenants = new List<Tenant>();
        private ILogger<MultitenantDbContext> _logger;

        public MultitenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<MultitenantDbContext> options, ITenantProvider tenantProvider, ILogger<MultitenantDbContext> logger)
            : base(options)

        {
            Tenants = tenantProvider.GetTenants();
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var t in Tenants)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"--> OnConfiguring Tenant: {t.Name}");
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(t.DatabaseConnectionString);
                base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            }

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Run the migrations from code/at runtime? https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/10/06/running-efcore-migrations-from-your-own-code/

Comment: it runs from code but the issue is only run on the last database from the list and also when I do remove-migration it also removed from same db.